# Using auto layout constraints programmatically create four UIView all with equal height and width

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

How can i create same view as below using auto layout constraints programmatically. I has been looking online for resource a while but i can't find any online tutorial to create and equalWidth and equalHeight constraints programmatically.

Please advise how can i set equalWidth and equalHeight programmatically to achieve layout like below.

[image]

Comment: First question. Are you sure that second layout is correct? Second question. Why don't you just disable landscape mode? If you disable landscape then just create the first layout then when you rotate it will stay the same and so create the second layout.

Comment: sorry i create this images quick for demo only. I wish to have all modes on (portrait and landscape). Using auto layout constraint programmatically to code this layout.

Comment: The Ray Wenderlich site has an AutoLayout tutorial that literally shows how to do this.

Comment: Note, they're not 50% of the height and width of the superview. An AutoLayout way of doing it would be to say that they are all equal height and equal width. (i.e. red.width == yellow.width == blue.width == green.width) etc...

Comment: yes thanks...i has edit the title to equal width and height

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this:

```
/*
 * ┌─┬─┐
 * │1│2│
 * ├─┼─┤
 * │3│4│
 * └─┴─┘
 */
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let view1 = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    let view2 = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    let view3 = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    let view4 = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)

    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    view3.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    view4.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    view1.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    view2.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    view3.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    view4.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    view.addSubview(view1)
    view.addSubview(view2)
    view.addSubview(view3)
    view.addSubview(view4)

    let views = ["view1":view1, "view2":view2, "view3":view3, "view4":view4]
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[view1][view2(==view1)]|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: views))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[view3][view4(==view3)]|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: views))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[view1][view3(==view1)]|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: views))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[view2][view4(==view2)]|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: views))


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: thanks rintaro for the complete answer...the code explain it self.

Comment: Hi @kaneyip , can you re-write the code using constraintWithItem: method ??